# Why auth code needed in authorization code flow?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I feel unclear about authorization code flow. the main difference between implicit flow and authorization code flow is that authorization code flow validates the client(using id and secret). first i define the steps of authorization code flow and I raise my doubt from them.

Authorization code flow steps(some of them skipped)

1. Authorization code request send to authorization server then user redirect to login page

   ```
      request contains

       - response_type=auth code
       - scope
       - state 
       - redirect_uri
       - client-id
   ```
2. if user credential are right then auth server redirect the url with auth code and state
3. client send post request to autherization server for access token

   ```
       request contains

          - grant type
          - code (auth code)
          - redirect_uri
          - client_id
          - client_secret

    once auth server validated above request we get access token as reponse
   ```
4. using the access token client will access the resource server

My question is why we're sending client secret on 3rd step instead of first step. what if we send client id and client secret in first step and redirect user to login page so after he logged in client can get access token directly why auth code related steps needed.

**How i expect above steps to be is**

1. user click the link so request send to auth server. which validates client id and secret if they're valid then user will be redirected to login page

   ```
    request contains
      - response_type: access token
      - scope
      - state 
      - redirect_uri
      - client-id
      - client-secret
   ```
2. if user credential are right then  auth server redirect the url with access token and state
3. using the access token client will access the resource server

client authentication can be done in first step why we need to drag it by sending client secret in 3rd step . why we need auth code related steps it's confusing can anyone explain the purpose of having auth code related steps?

Comment: this has to do with you cant hold a secret in the frontend client. The frontend client will start the login process, then after authentication get redirected to another backend service that actually holds the clients secret that will then do the code exchange using the client secrets and return the token to the frontend client. This service is usually called a BFF (backend for frontend). This is so that we know that we have a trusted service that validates the incoming code code, and then exchanges the code for a token.

Comment: never trust the client, never store secrets in the client.

Comment: this BFF is usually secured by using CORS, CSRF, and other security measures so that hopfully only our client can talk to it, and also why the codes that are getting passed to exchange for tokens are very short lived.

Comment: @Toerktumlare  so redirect uri must be front end which sends authcode to backend service so backend service will exchange the code for access token and return access token as response right?

Comment: Client(UI) sends the `redirect_uri` in the request with other fields to get the `oauth_code` from the Authorization server (BE). The authorization server redirects the `oauth_code` to the `redirect_uri` mentioned in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Because anything the authorization server (maybe Google) sends to the browser is logged to the browser. "auth code" is very short-lived (not more than 1 hour). An access token is long-lived so if the authorization server sends the access token to the browser in the first step, it would be logged to the browser so if it is compromised through the log, someone else would access to the app on your behalf.